# .htacces redirect home/category/product to home/product

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some issues:

1) how to redirect in .htaccess the `www.home/category1/category2/product1` to `www.home/product1` Just because having multiple pages for one product is obviously bad for targeting campaigns, seo etc.

2) I'm useing Open Cart witht the default .htaccess file, but can't manage to simply Redirect 301 any page. Getting a parametric URL that contains `?_route_=`
So for example I Redirect 301 `/category1/product1` to `/product1` and get a URL as `www.home.com/category1/product1?_route_=category1/product1` and an error 404 not found page. My .htaccess file is:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
    #RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have commented the sitemap rule.
I'm kindda out of options here,since I've already established manual Redirect 301s from couple pages, but I'm redirected to 404 not found each time.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place your 301 rule right at top before default routing rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category1/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still no effect on the redirect.

Comment: That is because of browser cache. Test this after clearing browser cache.